# RxJava BackPressureStrategy.DROP queues new tasks instead of dropping them

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have the code below in my Android activity which works as intended. on scroll events it invokes the `expensiveHttpCall()` through the `ThreadPoolExecutor` with `SynchronousQueue` & `DiscardPolicy` which results on new invokations to be discarded while the last invokation is still running.

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val recyclerView: RecyclerView
.
    val oneAtATimeExecutor = ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(),
            ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy()
    )

    private val scrollListener: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            Log.e("rx","triggered!")
            oneAtATimeExecutor.execute { expensiveHttpCall() }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        //...

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener)

        //...
    }

    private fun expensiveHttpCall() {
        Thread.sleep(2000L)
        Log.e("rx", "done!")
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble implementing the same behavior with `RxJava`'s `PublishProcessor`:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val recyclerView: RecyclerView

    val processor = PublishProcessor.create<Unit>()

    private val scrollListener: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            Log.e("rx","triggered!")
            processor.onNext(Unit)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        //...

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener)

        //...

        processor.onBackpressureDrop().observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .subscribe { expensiveHttpCall() }
    }

    private fun expensiveHttpCall() {
        Thread.sleep(2000L)
        Log.e("rx", "done!")
    }
}
```

To my surprise after a scroll the console prints out a bunch of `"triggered"` messages. then on a 2 second succession rate it prints `"done!"` for as many times as the number of `"triggered"` prints. this effectively behaves like a queue rather than as was intended.
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`observeOn` has an internal queue that will store a limited number of items. For synchronous tasks, you can limit the queue size to 1:

```
processor.onBackpressureDrop()
   .observeOn(Schedulers.io(), false, 1)
   .subscribe { expensiveHttpCall() }
```

for asnychronous subtasks, you can use `flatMap` with limited concurrency:

```
processor.onBackpressureDrop()
   .flatMap({
       Flowable.just(1)
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .doOnNext { expensiveHttpCall() }
   }, 1)
```

Comment: For async subtasks, is the ```.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())``` necessary? my ```expensiveHttpCall()``` in reality is a Single<Unit> which is already subscribedOn ```io```. Inside the ```flatMap``` block can't I just write : ```expensiveHttpCall.toFlowable()```?

Comment: This was just a standalone demonstration. If you have a fully prepared `Flowable`, just `flatMap` that directly without the extras here.